# YASID Science Fiction series question

Tags: story-identification

Trying to relocate a series I read a while back.

The premise behind the series is that humanity is all but wiped out by an alien attack.  The stories take place on a world which may be the last human colony.  It has been cut off from outside communication and lost all its technology.  There are several "states," and all are ruled by a theocracy that was set up to suppress technological advances so that they would remain undiscovered by the aliens, but all the technological knowledge was stored on the planet in some kind of AI installation until enough time passes that humanity can re-establish itself and build weapons to protect itself against the aliens, who are hidebound and not adept at innovation.  The theocracy has become corrupt, and the AI installation has created an android that goes to an island "state" that it considers the best chance for standing up to the theocracy and creating a new government that can foster the innovation, because it feels that enough time has passed.

The "state" it has chosen is an island that has a strong trade base, and the ruler has recently married the ruler of another state.  The android reintroduces gunpowder, schooner rigs for ships, etc.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sci-fi novel where humanity establish a colony with medieval technology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169612/sci-fi-novel-where-humanity-establish-a-colony-with-medieval-technology)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin [Site policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31394) is to close story-ID questions as duplicate only when the answer has been *confirmed* by the OP, either by accepting or in a comment. So for now I've cleared this from the review queue, but please do re-flag it if your answer is confirmed correct.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Noted; I thought that flagging as duplicate served a dual purpose, one of which was to point the querent to other questions that may have been overlooked before xi posted xir questions.

Comment: We don't close stories as duplicates unless we have confirmation that they are in fact the same story, @JeffZeitlin

Comment: @Edlothiad - noted, as that's exactly what Rand said. My comment to him was to clarify that I had been operating under a partial misunderstanding of the use of the dupe flag.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I apologise, Rand’s comment hadn’t appeared on my screen.

Answer (score 8):

See the answer to the proposed duplicate; you’re almost certainly looking for [David Weber’s Safehold series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safehold).

> **War against the fallen**
>
> Because signs of technology led the Gbaba to past emergency colonies, the mission on Safehold restricts all industrialization. Excepting Shan-Wei's team and her trusted staff, Administrator Eric Langhorne erases the memory of every colonist. Yet Langhorne follows his own plan: the colonists awaken programmed to believe they are the first humans, newly created by divine will. They worship Langhorne as the leader of God's "Archangels", charged with guiding a permanent pretechnical society.
>
> Shan-Wei tries to defy this plan, but is labeled a traitor and killed, along with most of her followers, at their Alexandria settlement by a hidden orbital weapon. Shan-Wei's side retaliates, killing Langhorne and most of his allies, sparking the "War Against the Fallen" among the survivors. Langhorne's "Church of God Awaiting" eventually prevails and sets up a militantly technophobic global theocracy, which deifies and worships Langhorne and demonizes Shan-Wei.
>
> Centuries pass before Shan-Wei's backup plan comes into being. During the terraforming process, Shan-Wei hid an android, with the personality and memories of Nimue Alban, a Terran Federation Navy tactical officer, deep within a secret mountain base. "Nimue's Cave” is stocked with an AI military computer and a room full of technology. When Nimue awakens, she accepts a mission to destroy the Church and uplift humanity.

Comment: Having read that enjoyable series, I would ten to agree that this is a good answer. Every point by the OP is matched by the answer, accurate to the book.